# Compiling 64 bit sqlite for windows and linux

Tags: database, sqlite, compiler-errors

There is no 64bit version of Sqlite available for either linux or windows from http://sqlite.org/download.html.

How to compile the sqlite library for 64 bit OS? and how do you ensure that the generated code will pass all the tests that are performed on a release build of Sqlite. i.e.
http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html

How to ensure that there are no compiler introduced errors in the generated code?

Comment: most open source projects have a `make config; make; make test; make install` sequence to run their own internal tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on UNIX and LINUX systems, I'll test this to see whether it really makes a 64bit sqlite3

CPPFLAGS=-m64 ./configure
make 
make install